# about mysql excute order by 1 and rand(1)?

Tags: mysql, random, sql-order-by

In mysql I built a table, which id is int type, name and password is varchar type.
excute

```
select * from test.new_table order by rand(1);
```

then the result is:
[image]

This is because after set seed for rand the sequence is fixed, I already know.But if excute

```
select * from test.new_table order by 1 and rand(1);
```

then the result is:
[image]

For such a result I do not understand. In addition, if excute order by 'xxx' the results are arranged.
Not quite understand, hope you to give pointers.

Comment: Are you executing these two queries from within the same session?  If so, you should _not_ be seeing the order of the result set changing.

Comment: They are in the same session exactly.But the result changed.You can test it in mysql.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the `and` operator? Do you mean to do a bitwise `and` or are you try to do an order by the 1st column and then randomly thereafter? In that case, you'd use a comma instead of `and`.

Comment: @siride, `ORDER BY 1, RAND(1)` would order by the primary key `id` column first, then by a random value if there's a tie—which there will never be, assuming `id` is the primary key.

Comment: @BillKarwin: it doesn't make sense either, but it least it fits the way ORDER BY clauses work.

Comment: this is a bug of mysql.Thanks for your answer and concern.

Comment: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=82011

Answer (score 0):

You can view the results of the expression as part of your query:

```
mysql> select *, 1, rand(1), 1 and rand(1) from new_table order by 1 and rand(1);
+----+------+----------+---+---------------------+---------------+
| id | name | password | 1 | rand(1)             | 1 and rand(1) |
+----+------+----------+---+---------------------+---------------+
|  1 | ghi  | 111      | 1 | 0.40540353712197724 |             1 |
|  3 | abc  | 234      | 1 |  0.1418603212962489 |             1 |
|  5 | 5    | 5        | 1 | 0.04671454713373868 |             1 |
|  7 | 7    | 7        | 1 |     0.6108337804776 |             1 |
|  2 | jkl  | 123      | 1 |  0.8716141803857071 |             1 |
|  4 | def  | 555      | 1 | 0.09445909605776807 |             1 |
|  6 | 6    | 6        | 1 |  0.9501954782290342 |             1 |
+----+------+----------+---+---------------------+---------------+
```

See how the **boolean** expression always results in `1`?

As @Barmar described, any expression `1 and n` results in either 0 or 1, depending on the value of n being zero or nonzero.

So your expression `ORDER BY 1 AND RAND(1)` is just like `ORDER BY true` (a constant expression) which means the ordering is a tie between every row, and MySQL orders them in an arbitrary way.

But *arbitrary* is not the same as *random*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.It turned out this is a bug.

Comment: How is this related to that bug, which is about the `WHERE` clause? `ORDER BY` isn't a condition.

Comment: @Barmar, if the expression is evaluated incorrectly, it could affect anywhere the expression is used. But I haven't reproduced the bug myself.